# Selenium get text in paragraph after div

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I have a page that looks like this:
[image]

When we look at the HTML code:
[image]

So it first gives the title of the paragraph in a `div` and then under it it will have the paragraph. So ideally I want to do something like `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Objectives of the Course')` and then say "get next element" (i.e. the paragraph under it).

How can this be done using selenium or any other library?

---

Comment: Can you share the url and does solution have to be selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text within `<p>` tag which is just under the title **Objectives of the Course** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='FieldsetBaslik' and contains(., 'Objectives of the Course')]//following::p[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `text`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='FieldsetBaslik' and contains(., 'Objectives of the Course')]//following::p[1]"))).text)
  ```

---

### Outro

As per the documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Although the other answer is way easier I think this one is more suited for more complex tasks, for example the other answer won't work when there would be `div`s with the same name (`FieldsetBaslik`) but a different text

Comment: Looks like the xpath you're suggesting is the answer to the question. IMHO, the WebDriverWait stuff is unrelated to the question. For example, if that HTML is statically loaded with the page then there's no reason to wait for it.

Comment: @ArnonAxelrod You are correct. Did you observe the `== $0` present in the html?

Answer (score 3):

You may use XPATH or CSS Selector with `find_element_by_css_selector` method

in this HTML:

```
<div class="title"> title </div>
<p> content </p>
```

you can select next sibling with this:

```
div.title + p {
  color: red;
}
```

so in your case, `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.FieldsetBaslik+p')` will work

check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: Dammn this was an easy solution!, awesome how you can just add `+p`